# Adding html to the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to attach string html to the DOM using jQuery:

I have this HTML string:

```
 var html = "<div id="inspectorMenu" style="display: none;">"+
            "<label id="showInspectorName"  style="padding: 13px 09px; color:white"></label>"+
            "<ul id="" class="nav pull-left">"+
            "<li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center; max-height:35px;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sites.list" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אתרים"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></i></a></li>"+
            "<li style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;max-height:35px;"><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="sitesDamages.sitesList" style="padding: 11px 09px;" title="אירועים"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i></a></li>"+
            "</ul>"+
            "</div>"
```

And I have this html code:

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("sites maintaice", "Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

  //===========I need to add html string here!!!==============//

    </div>
```

Using jQuery I need to add html string between  `</div>` tag and  `@Html.ActionLink` .

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Give your navbar-header an ID, then do document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += yourHTML; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert the HTML after the markup generated by `@Html.ActionLink`, at the end of the DIV, you can append

```
$(".navbar-header").append(html);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I need to remove at some point the added html?

Comment: @Michael you should add Id to that element (to that html) and then i.e. 
`$('#thatGivenId').remove()` or `$('#thatGivenId').hide()`